# SQL Group by Max Date Including Null

Tags: sql, ms-access

The code below groups multiple records with the same project name and different dates.

The problem is that some dates in the date field is null. I need a way for this code to include the max date or a null value.

I tried adding Or Is Null under Dates but then that just brings me back to my problem with projects having multiple records

Original SQL

```
SELECT t1.Project_Name, t1.IssueNmb, t1.Date
FROM Milestones_Detail_Report_Table AS t1
WHERE (((t1.Date)=(SELECT Max(t2.Date) 
     FROM Table_Name t2 
     WHERE t2.Project_Name=t1.Project_Name
     GROUP BY t2.Project_Name)))
```

SQL with OR

```
SELECT t1.Project_Name, t1.IssueNmb, t1.Date
FROM Milestones_Detail_Report_Table AS t1
WHERE (((t1.Date)=(SELECT Max(t2.Date) 
     FROM Table_Name t2 
     WHERE t2.Project_Name=t1.Project_Name
     GROUP BY t2.Project_Name))) OR (((t1.Date) Is Null));
```

Table: TableName

```
Project_Name |  IssueNmb | Date
------------------------
  Car        |    1      | 1/1/15
  Car        |    1      | 2/1/15 <--This record populates
  House      |    1      |        <--This record does NOT populate
```

Comment: Please show sample results.  What do you mean "I need a way for this code to include the max date or a null value"?

Comment: You can replace null with default value, let's say: `1899-01-01`. Use `Iif()` function

Answer (score 1):

You might want this `where` clause:

```
WHERE (t1.Date IS NULL) OR
      (t1.Date = (SELECT iif(COUNT(*) <> COUNT(t2.Date), NULL, Max(t2.Date))
                  FROM Table_Name t2 
                  WHERE t2.Project_Name = t1.Project_Name
                 )
      )
```

This will treat `NULL` as the maximum date, so there will be no matches on the subquery if any values of `t2.Date` are `NULL` for a given project.

Note that you do not need the `group by` in the subquery.

Comment: not knowing what data actually is in `t2` it might make sense to add `LIMIT 1` to the subquery

Comment: This is what I put in and I get "Undefined function 'iff' in expression:  `SELECT t1.Project_Name, t1.IssueNmb, t1.Date
FROM TableName AS t1
WHERE (((t1.Date) Is Null Or (t1.Date)=(SELECT iff(COUNT(*) <> COUNT(t2.Date), NULL, Max(t2.Date))
                  FROM TableName 
                  WHERE t2.Project_Name = t1.Project_Name
                 )));`

Comment: @user4581436 . . . The function is `iif()` not `iff()`.

Comment: This code everything is Date field null. Also it did not pick the max date from each set of records. `SELECT t1.Project_Name, t1.IssueNmb, t1.Date
FROM TableName AS t1
WHERE (((t1.Date) Is Null Or (t1.Date)=(SELECT iif(COUNT(*) <> COUNT(t2.Date), NULL, Max(t2.Date))
From TableName t2 
WHERE t2.Project_Name = t1.Project_Name)));` Please help.

Comment: @user4581436 . . . That would be true if all projects had a null date.